# Java, How to calculate euclidean distance from neighbours matrix and XY coordinates

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to use Dijkstra's Algorithm to find shortest path through a route. Current I have the neighbors in an adjacency matrix 2D array. 1 if connected to other node and 0 if not connected like so.

```
public static void buildMatrix(String[] data)
{

    int[][] neighbours = new int[numberOfNodes][];

    for (int row= 0; row < noOfCaves; row++){
        neighbours[row] = new int[numberOfNodes];
    }

    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;

    for (int point = (numberOfNode*2)+1 ; point < data.length;      point++){            

        if (data[point].equals("1"))
            neighbours[row][col] = 1;
        else
            neighbours[row][col] = 0;

        row++;
        if (row == numberOfNodes){
            row=0;
            col++;
        }

    }
}
```

I then have the X, Y coordinates saved into another 2D Array like so

```
int Ref = 0;
int a = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < (numberOfNodes * 2) + 1; i++)
{
    coordinates[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(data[i]);

    if (y == 0) { y = 1; } 
    else { y = 0; x++; }
}
```

This gives me a 2D Array that looks like this with X Y Coordinates - coords [[5, 7], [4, 5], [13, 6], [5, 9], [10, 4], [8, 6], [14, 1]].

How do I use these two arrays to calculate the euclidean distance so that I get the distance of the nodes and their neighbors?

Comment: are these the coordinates, in your 2D array, of all the neighbors to a given node?

Comment: Yes, I have it working now and the below answer was helpful for me to figure out the calculation needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If node `i` is connected to node `j` then the euclidian distance should be calculated using the matrix containing the coordinated `coords` like this:

```
Math.sqrt((coords[i][0] - coords[j][0]) * (coords[i][0] - coords[j][0]) + 
          (coords[i][1] - coords[j][1]) * (coords[i][1] - coords[j][1]))
```

This is the euclidian distance formula for two dimensions.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful for me to figure out the calculation needed.